# Wordpress dropdown issue

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

I've created my standard Wordpress menu, including submenu items and for some reason have ran into an issue - the dropdown item appears on page load, and disappears when I hover it then mouse out.

Applying CSS to hide the .sub-menu by default doesn't fix the issue, and I'm inclined to think it's my CSS conflicting but I can't see why. Anyone got any ideas?

The wp_nav_menu output is:

```
<!-- Navigation -->
<div class="navigate hidden-xs hidden-sm" role="navigation" style="position: relative;">
    <ul>
        <div class="menu-primary-navigation-container">
            <ul id="menu-primary-navigation-1" class="menu">
                <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-11 current_page_item menu-item-14"><a href="http://localhost/aes-wp/">Home</a></li>
                <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-9"><a href="http://localhost/aes-wp/about-us/">About Us</a></li>
                <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-23"><a href="http://localhost/aes-wp/product-areas/">Product Areas</a>
                   <ul class="sub-menu">
                       <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-26"><a href="http://localhost/aes-wp/product-areas/dust-fume-extraction/">Dust and Fume Extraction</a></li>
                   </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-17"><a href="http://localhost/aes-wp/news/">News</a></li>
            </ul>
         </div>          
      </ul>
      <a href="#" class="shop">Shop <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart" style="color: #fff;"></i></a>
    </div>
    <!-- END Navigation -->
```

...and my associated CSS is as follows:

```
header .navigate ul li:first-child a {
  border-top-left-radius:     5px; 
  border-bottom-left-radius:  5px; 
  margin-left:                -10px;
}

header .navigate {
  margin:                   120px 0 30px 0;
  width:                    100%;
  height:                   48px;
  border-radius:            5px;
  background:               url("assets/img/nav.png") repeat-x;
}

header .navigate ul:first-child {
  list-style-type:          none;
  margin:                   0;
  padding:                  0 0 0 5px;
  height:                   48px;
  width:                    100%;
  position:                 relative;
}

header .navigate ul:first-child li {
  display:                  block;
  float:                    left;
  height:                   48px;
}

header .navigate ul:first-child li a {
  display:                  block;
  height:                   48px;
  font-size:                14px;
  font-family:              'novnormal', serif;
  color:                    #fff;
  line-height:              48px;
  padding:                  0 15px 0 15px;
}

header .navigate ul li a:hover,
header .navigate ul li a.active,
header .navigate ul li.current-menu-item a {
  text-decoration:          none;
  background:               #8abb06 !important;
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help guys!

Comment: Do you have a url to see?

Comment: I'm on localhost, sorry - if it helps narrow it down, the dropdown is displayed on page when it first loads - hovering its parent actually removes it - the exact opposite of what I'm trying to achieve!

Comment: Where is your jQuery / JS code?

Comment: Non existant? I'm trying to utilise Wordpress' inbuilt features - something's triggering to hide the menu so I assumed it was preloaded?

Comment: If it dissappears after loading, I would suggest it is javascript causing this behaviour - without having a URL its difficult to help.

Comment: Nope, WordPress does not have built in dropdown menus. Either you, a plugin, or the theme developer is controlling such actions.

Comment: Out of the box on the default theme, the dropdowns are controlled via CSS

Comment: Have you checked the console to see that there is indeed no JS error when hovering over the menu, it's a silly question but sometimes it's the simplest things that are the culprit!

Comment: Also have you tried disabling any plugins you have installed to see if they are having a knock on effect?

Comment: @Chris Thanks for that info ;) I did not know the OP was using the default theme.

Comment: I've popped a copy online:
http://www.bbdclients.com/aes-wp/

You'll see the menu in question up top!

Comment: Also no error output in the console - all seems fine on face-value. I still smell stinky CSS but I can't narrow down the issue :(

Comment: I can only see html on the page, styles aren't pulling through - your stylesheets are referencing localhost?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to update the URL when I uploaded. Should be pulling in ok now!

Comment: Still pulling my hair out over this - anyone having any luck seeing obvious issues?

Comment: $('.navigate ul li ul').bind('mouseleave', function() {
  $(this).hide();
}); this is causin the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some javascript in aes theme, custom.js which is acting on it eg.

```
$('.navigate ul li ul').bind('mouseleave', function() {
  $(this).hide();
});
```

To confirm that it is javascript interfering, disable javascript in the browser and it no longer disappears when you mouse out.

Some quick css that might give the desired behavior:

```
ul.sub-menu {
display: none;
position: absolute;
}

.menu:hover ul.sub-menu {
  display: block;
}
```

You might prefer a different way in particular to the absolute position - but that might be a starting point.

Comment: Good spot - js removed but the menu still isn't working properly - it doesn't disappear on hover now, at least. Any ideas why it's stuck visible and why it forces the width of the parent ul to match its own?

Comment: It looks like it's just lacking some css or javascript to do that.

Comment: Added some quick css to my reply.

Comment: I tried that CSS but it doesn't seem to make a difference :(

Comment: My mistake, missed the "-".. should be sub-menu

Comment: You rock - that worked and I can now style the dropdown accordingly. Before I move on to the next headache - if I want the same result adding a third level menu item, how do I achieve this? Do I target:

    ul.sub-menu li ul.sub-menu

Comment: Yes all subsequent levels have the same class .sub-menu - but note that because of this, the above code will target all of them. That's not likely to work well so you can adjust it to target only the initial dropdown like this: .menu>li>ul.sub-menu